# Is "static class imports" actually an announced or hinted at future feature of C#?

Tags: c#, static-import

Starting from [this edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29&diff=490179471&oldid=489980512), the [Wikipedia article on C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) mentions "static class imports" as a future feature of C#, alongside "Compiler-as-a-service ("Roslyn")".

Has this feature actually been announced or hinted at by a member of the compiler team or is this just wild speculation?

Comment: [As always, whenever I discuss the hypothetical "next version of C#", keep in mind that we have not announced any next version, that it might never happen, and that it is utterly premature to think about feature sets or schedules. All speculation about future versions of unannounced products should be taken as "for entertainment purposes only" musings, not as promises about future offerings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx) -- Eric

Comment: [I have removed that claim.](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29&diff=497371550&oldid=496824526) Nothing like that was officially announced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the Eric Lippert's article that's most likely the source of this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx), he's discussing using C# as a scripting language. And, the Roslyn CTP includes C# Interactive window and a C# scripting engine.

C# Interactive uses a somewhat different version of C#. For example, you don't always need semicolons, and you can have top-level methods and top-level statements. And you can also use static class imports:

```
> using System.Math;
> Abs(-5)
5
```

Because of this, I think static class imports (along with the other “scripty” features I mentioned) won't be included in the normal version of C#, but you will be able to use them in C# scripts.

Answer (score 2):

[Eric Lippert made a post about this feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx) but he didn't promise an implementation.